# Modify a Solidworks Global Variable Value - C#

Tags: c#, solidworks

I am trying to modify global variables within my C# code.

Based on these two examples:

[Re: Macro change global variable](https://forum.solidworks.com/message/549584#549584)

[2015 SOLIDWORKS API Help - Add and Modify Equations Example (C#)](https://forum.solidworks.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.solidworks.com%2F2015%2Fenglish%2Fapi%2Fsldworksapi%2Fadd_equations_example_csharp.htm)

I have come up with the following code, but it doesn't change the global variables. Also, when I go into the equation manager after the code runs it has red Xs by the equations and says "The syntax of this equation is incorrect".

```
string depth = "\"Depth\" = " + param["Part"].Substring(0, param["Part"].IndexOf("x"));
string flangeWidth = "\"FlangeWidth\" = " + param["Width"];

swEquationMgr = swModel.GetEquationMgr();
swEquationMgr.SetEquationAndConfigurationOption(0, depth, (int)swInConfigurationOpts_e.swAllConfiguration, null);
swEquationMgr.SetEquationAndConfigurationOption(0, flangeWidth, (int)swInConfigurationOpts_e.swAllConfiguration, null);
```

NOTE: The depth variable correctly evaluates to ("Depth" = 8) & flangeWidth evaluates to ("FlangeWidth" = 3.5).

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to modify any variable **based on its name!** This is unique as most other code samples show you how to set a variable by its index!

```
Sub SetVar(NAME As String, VALUE As Variant)
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swEqnMgr = swModel.GetEquationMgr

    For i = 0 To swEqnMgr.GetCount - 1
        vSplit = Split(swEqnMgr.Equation(i), " = ")
        vSplit(0) = Replace(vSplit(0), Chr(34), Empty)
        If vSplit(0) = NAME Then _
            swEqnMgr.Equation(i) = Replace(swEqnMgr.Equation(i), vSplit(1), VALUE)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

The SetEquationAndConfigurationOption() can only be used on equations added using the [IEquationMgr::IAdd3.](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IEquationMgr~IAdd3.html) method.  Were the equations added using that method?

I used:

```
string depth = "\"Depth\" = 4";
string flangeWidth = "\"FlangeWidth\" = 7";
```

and was able to get the global variables to change only after adding using the Add3 method (which requires multiple configurations).  Add2 with a single configuration did not work for me.

Also, the first parameter of the SetEquationAndConfigurationOption is the index, you have both at 0, they would need to be modified to match where they are in your global variables (starting at 0).  Such as:

```
swEquationMgr.SetEquationAndConfigurationOption(0, depth, (int)swInConfigurationOpts_e.swAllConfiguration, null);
swEquationMgr.SetEquationAndConfigurationOption(1, flangeWidth, (int)swInConfigurationOpts_e.swAllConfiguration, null);
```